# TypeScript conditional property not working with Omit

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I created a baseProps type and if I use that type directly then I'm able to call `prop.onHotSave()` if `prop.hotSave` is true.

But when I make a new prop using Omit then it no longer works.

```
 type BaseProps = {
  commonProp: string;
  propToRemove: () => void;
} & (
  { hotSave: true, onHotSave: () => void } |
  { hotSave: false }
)

const thisWorks = (props: BaseProps) => {
    if (props.hotSave) {
        props.onHotSave();
    }
}

type NewProps = Omit<BaseProps, 'onKeyDown'>;

const thisDoesNotWork = (props: NewProps) => {
    if (props.hotSave) {
        props.onHotSave();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When being passed as a parameter to `Omit`, `BaseProps` is being aggregated to:

```
{
    commonProp: string;
    propToRemove: () => void;
    hotSave: boolean;
}
```

As a solution to this problem, you could use a kind of hack which consists in using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) like this:

```
type NewProps<T> = T extends T ? Omit<T, 'onKeyDown'> : never;

const thisDoesNotWork = (props: NewProps<BaseProps>) => {
    if (props.hotSave) {
        props.onHotSave();
    }
}
```

This allows the `Omit` helper to be applied on every element of the base union type.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQFwngDgpsBCCGBnKAFATgewo4BeYA3gFDDADGGAtpRgHbpYBcwiIaAlrQOYDcJwETBAAqGAEpQaANyjMAFAEo8APmBSM7ACZ8AvsABkwOfwLAAFhhABleDOZsArlAA0wOgAlLNu0aW5V6lrAegA%20JuZetrLAAGbwADbIwUQKREQUtKygZuyIAOoYaADWOPhygliIzAjIDNh%20qsSkpOwxRhXYAHQW1lFKTc2DHYidHpEyinyDOkQzRODQwAByUADudYgAPMKq%20MLAUAAeIFC0mjj7APzAAPKU7CDbrgDkdADSUGAAIhirtM%20qZi0KAyNB8dJ0LIgHKIH5QRBLSwFYp4dpCKrLNYbTY1VDo5QNQj8Fptcro7rjKD9YmDATksa9CYKKbNGY6IA)